# jstl if : Changing output Value When Click Radio Button

Tags: jsp, radio-button, jstl

here it's the case

so i would like to change the output value when i click radio button 
and what should i do?

i've done this one

```
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="CardA" >Card A
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="CardB">Card B

<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${radio=='CardA'}">
    <c:out value="CARD A"></c:out>
    <br />
   </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:out value="CARD B"/>
  <br />
    </c:otherwise>

   </c:choose>
```

on that example when i click radio button which have value Card A i want to print c:out value Card A

What Should i do? did i do something wrong?

Comment: You have to send another request and come with your radio button's value setting it with request object..

Answer (score 1):

Since the action of selecting a radio button is client side you will need to implement some way to handle the dynamic behaviour required.

Remember JSP is rendered as HTML - once it is on the page it is static.

To implement the behaviour you want you will need to either use Javascript(recommended) or submit your page and handle the logic server-side before returning the new page.

If you are open to using jQuery the .change() function would be applicable here:

http://api.jquery.com/change/